# WPF validation not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox, wpf-controls

I have a `TextBox` on WPF that I want to validate. I'm using `Binding` to validate it:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" TabIndex="0" LostFocus="TextBox_OnLostFocus">
</TextBox>
```

The `LostFocus` event:

```
private void TextBox_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Control) sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
}
```

Code behind the validation:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));

    }
}

public string Error { get { return this[null]; } }

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        columnName = columnName ?? string.Empty;
        if (columnName == string.Empty || columnName == "Name")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
            {
                result += Properties.Resources.ValidationName + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        return result.TrimEnd();
    }
}
```

I have some questions:

**1.** When I first load my Window, my control is surrounded by a red square (the validation one), but I want it to appear only when I fire it (on the `Explicit` side).

**2.** How can I know if all my fields have been validated? I mean, when I press a button I **only need to know** how to know if all controls **have been validated**.

**NOTE:** I do have this context on the Constructor:

```
User u = new User();
DataContext = u;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your first question may be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516588/binding-updatesourcetrigger-explicit-updates-source-at-program-startup) Did you try setting the binding mode to Default?
2. The [Validation.HasError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.haserror.aspx) Attached Property will tell you if any binding on a particular UI Element has any binding validation errors. Use that on every control you need to have validated. Try that first. If you are using a pattern like MVVM, you could create properties on your VM to bind to the Validation.HasError properties.

Comment: The `Validation.HasError` did solve the second question, but the first one still remains. When I load my textbox it still remains red...

Comment: Propably because your property is invalid already. I consider it good practice that it does that. Why is an empty filename ok when you open the window, but not after you added one character and then deleted it?

Comment: I agree you, @dowhilefor, but in part. On first load, I don't see so practical that it's red, as it's not obvious, as the user didn't wrote anything yet. So I'm not sure on how to avoid that (only for visual practces). On the otherhand, I misunderstood siz too. I changed Mode to Default, but it still remains red.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my problem had something to do with the class I used to validate. The class does this:

```
public ErrorProvider()
{
    this.DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(ErrorProvider_DataContextChanged);
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ErrorProvider_Loaded);
}
```

So whenever it first loads, it suscribes to the `Load` event and then it launches this:

```
private void ErrorProvider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Validate();
}
```

so I commented it, and launched the `Validate()` method when needed....